# iOS offline app html5, google maps not loading on app, just on safari

Tags: html, google-maps, ios6, mobile-safari, offlineapps

so i have a web app, when i save to iphone the google maps, sometimes load, but not every time, using safari on iphone it`s always loading.

the manifest file content:

```
CACHE MANIFEST
favicon.ico
index.html
enviar-imagens.php
css/mobile.css
css/upload-style.css
images/logo-mobile.png
js/jquery.maskMoney.js
js/jquery.maskedinput-1.3.js
test.js
js/jquery.min.js
images/inicial_retina.png

NETWORK:
*
anunciar-passo2.php
https://maps.googleapis.com/
http://maps.gstatic.com/
http://maps.google.com/
http://maps.googleapis.com/
http://mt0.googleapis.com/
http://mt1.googleapis.com/
http://mt2.googleapis.com/
http://mt3.googleapis.com/
http://khm0.googleapis.com/
http://khm1.googleapis.com/
http://cbk0.googleapis.com/
http://cbk1.googleapis.com/
http://www.google-analytics.com/
http://gg.google.com/
```

The page with map:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=(mykey)&v=3.exp&sensor=true"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">



      var map;

      function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
          zoom: 18,
          panControl: true,
             zoomControl: true,
             scaleControl: true,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
            mapOptions);


 //Delay customizations until the map has loaded
    var element = document.createElement('script');
    element.src = 'test.js';
    element.type = 'text/javascript';
    var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    scripts.parentNode.insertBefore(element, scripts);



      }

 google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
```

I'm also using php no-cache on this page.
Using pc browser always works, just on mobile offline app the map sometimes not load.

I tryed this configs http://blogs.missouristate.edu/web/2010/05/12/google-maps-api-v3-developing-for-mobile-devices/
with no success

the mime.types is with manifest config.